# CSS skewed element disappears after rotation

Tags: css

I have a child div (text separator) which is transformed with skew in main block of code.
When screen width reaches mobile format container with text and separator should rotate, but after rotation it disappears (see below screenshots). If I make width of the browser very small it appears again.
Couldn't find a solution to this, I'm close to just replacing coloured div with image, but if possible I'd like to make this work.

[normal state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D46ao.png)

[rotated state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3R3H.png)

[narrow state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqmdq.png)

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cantarell:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400;1,700&family=Kanit:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;1,200;1,300&family=Righteous&display=swap");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Darker+Grotesque:wght@300;400;500;600;700;900&display=swap");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Prompt:ital,wght@0,900;1,900&display=swap");

.s-divider {
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 40px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 20px;
}

.s-divider:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  margin: -25px auto 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 125px/12px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px white;
}

#topBtn {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 150px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  right: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 99;
  border: solid 1px lightgray;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px lightgrey;
  outline: none;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#topBtn:active {
  box-shadow: #acacba 2px 3px 7px inset;
  transform: translateY(3px);
}

#topBtn img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 52px;
  max-width: 1440px;
  display: flex;
  top: 0;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.topnav {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  font-family: "Cantarell", sans-serif;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  transform: scale(1.05);
  border-radius: 40px;
  font-family: "Cantarell", sans-serif;
}

.front-name {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1440px;
  height: 600px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.front-name .name-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.front-name .name-container .parallelogram {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 700px;
  height: 8px;
  transform: skew(85deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(85deg);
  background: linear-gradient(190deg, #2a8aff, #b53fff);
  margin-left: 45px;
  margin-right: 65px;
}

.front-name .name-container .name1 {
  text-align: start;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
.front-name .name-container .name2 {
  text-align: end;
  height: 120px;
  line-height: 120px;
  width: 100%;
}

.front-name .name-container p {
  -webkit-text-stroke: 2px white;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  font-family: "Prompt", sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 120px;
  margin: 0;
  text-size-adjust: auto;
}

.front-name .name-container .name2 p {
  font-style: italic;
  text-shadow: 0 0 #00162d, -1px 0 #cdd2d5, -1px 2px #808d93, -2px 1px #cdd2d5, -2px 3px #808d93, -3px 2px #cdd2d5, -3px 4px #808d93, -4px 3px #cdd2d5, -4px 5px #808d93, -5px 4px #cdd2d5, -5px 6px #808d93, -6px 5px #cdd2d5, -6px 7px #808d93, -7px 6px #cdd2d5, -7px 8px #808d93, -8px 7px #cdd2d5;
}

html {
  scroll-padding-top: 65px;
}

body {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: #00162d;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 35px;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-family: "Darker Grotesque", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.aboutMe {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in;
}

.aboutMe .box .about h2 {
  text-align: start;
}

.aboutMe .box {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.aboutMe .box .about {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  height: auto;
}

.aboutMe .box .about p {
  color: white;
  text-align: start;
  font-size: 2.125rem;
  line-height: 2.5rem;
  font-family: "Darker Grotesque", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.aboutMe .box .about .about-image {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: right;
  margin-top: 80px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.aboutMe .box .about .about-image img {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 280px;
}

.box .project {
  background: linear-gradient(130deg, #2a8aff, #b53fff);
  height: 150px;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  margin: 70px 35px;
  z-index: auto;
  color: white;
}

.projects {
  height: auto;
}

.projects h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

.project .button_proj {
  height: 50px;
  width: 260px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -25px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  color: black;
}

.project .button_proj .button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  background-color: white;
  font-family: "Kanit", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.project .button_proj .button:active {
  box-shadow: #acacba 2px 3px 7px inset;
  transform: translateY(3px);
}

.project p {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 15px;
  line-height: 1.3;
  font-family: "Kanit", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.prj_img {
  width: 280px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: azure;
  position: absolute;
  top: -90px;
  border: solid 1px whitesmoke;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: transform 0.45s ease-in-out;
}

.prj_img img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.project .prj_img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.3, 1.3);
  z-index: 2;
}

.projects .box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#skills {
  margin: 0px 30px 30px 30px;
}

.skills_img {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.skills_img img {
  width: 12%;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 12px #96d7ff) drop-shadow(0 0 3.5px #96d7ff);
  min-width: 79px;
  margin: 0 8px;
}

.s-divider img {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 4px;
  max-width: 60px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 1px dashed #aaa;
}

.contactField {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  height: 200px;
  display: table;
}

.contactField p {
  font-size: 20px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Kanit", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: whitesmoke;
  letter-spacing: 0.25px;
}

.main-social-container .social-box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.main-social-container .social-box .social {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 94% 25%, 94% 75%, 50% 100%, 7% 75%, 7% 25%);
}

.main-social-container .social-box .social img {
  object-fit: contain;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: linear-gradient(190deg, #2a8aff, #b53fff);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 860px) {
  .front-name .name-container {
    max-width: 860px;
  }

  .front-name .name-container p {
    font-size: 6.25rem;
  }
  .front-name .name-container .name1 {
    text-align: left;
    height: 90px;
  }
  .front-name .name-container .name2 {
    text-align: right;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
  }

  .front-name .name-container .parallelogram {
    max-width: 600px;
    margin-left: 45px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .aboutMe .box {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .aboutMe .box .about .about-image img {
    margin-right: 30px;
  }

  .topnav {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }

  .aboutMe .box .about .about-image {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: right;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 750px) {
  .front-name .name-container {
    max-width: 750px;
  }

  .front-name .name-container .parallelogram {
    max-width: 500px;
    margin-left: 45px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  .front-name .name-container {
    max-width: 650px;
  }

  .front-name .name-container p {
    font-size: 4.25rem;
  }
  .front-name .name-container .name1 {
    text-align: left;
    height: 80px;
  }
  .front-name .name-container .name2 {
    text-align: right;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 70px;
  }

  .front-name .name-container .parallelogram {
    max-width: 400px;
    margin-left: 45px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 545px) {
  .front-name .name-container {
    max-width: 650px;
    transform: rotate(35deg);
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 20px;
  }

  .front-name .name-container p {
    font-size: 4.25rem;
  }
  .front-name .name-container .name1 {
    text-align: left;
    height: 80px;
  }
  .front-name .name-container .name2 {
    text-align: right;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 70px;
  }

  .front-name .name-container .parallelogram {
    max-width: 300px;
    margin-left: 45px;
  }

  .aboutMe .box .about {
    max-width: 470px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  #topBtn {
    bottom: 200px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 510px) {
  .aboutMe .box .about {
    max-width: 420px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 414px) {
  .aboutMe .box .about {
    max-width: 390px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 390px) {
  .aboutMe .box .about {
    max-width: 350px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Personal Website</title>
    <link href="styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  </head>

  <body>

    <button onclick="topFunction()" id="topBtn" title="Go to top">
      <img src="images/arrow_top.png">
    </button>

    <!--Navbar-->
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="topnav">
        <a class="active" href="#aboutMe">ABOUT ME</a>
        <a href="index.html#projects">PROJECTS</a>
        <a href="index.html#skills">SKILLS</a>
        <a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="front-name">
      <div class="name-container">
        <div class="name1">
          <p>PERSONAL</p>
        </div>

        <div class="parallelogram"></div>

        <div class="name2">
          <p>WEBSITE</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!--About Me section-->
    <div class="aboutMe" id="aboutMe">
      <div class="s-divider">
        <div class="shadow"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="about">
          <h2>ABOUT ME</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="about">
          <div class="about-image">
            <img src="images/polaroid.png" alt="photo" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <!--Section Divider-->
    <div class="s-divider"></div>

    <!--Projects Section-->
    <div class="projects" id="projects">
      <h2>PROJECTS</h2>
      
      <div class="box">
        <div class="project">
          <div class="prj_img">
            <img src="images/tea-cosy.png" alt="web_image">
          </div>
          <p>Fictional Tea Shop Website</p>
          <div class="button_proj">
            <a href="https://freemasoid.github.io/Tea-Cosy/">
              <button class="button">WEB</button>
            </a>
            <a href="https://github.com/Freemasoid/Tea-Cosy.git">
              <button class="button" url>SOURCE</button>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="project">
          <div class="prj_img">
            <img src="images/sky-thunder.png" alt="web_image">
          </div>
          <p>
            Flexbox and responsive design practice.<br />
            Airline Website.
          </p>
          <div class="button_proj">
            <a href="https://freemasoid.github.io/Company_Website/">
              <button class="button">WEB</button>
            </a>
            <a href="https://github.com/Freemasoid/Company_Website.git">
              <button class="button" url>SOURCE</button>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="box">
        <div class="project">
          <div class="prj_img">
            <img src="images/random.png" alt="web_image" />
          </div>
          <p>Random message generator. Displays message based on dice value after roll.</p>
          <div class="button_proj">
            <a href="https://github.com/Freemasoid/Random_Message.git">
              <button class="button" url>SOURCE</button>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="project">
          <div class="prj_img"><p>WEB IMAGE</p></div>
          <p>
            To be continued...
          </p>
          <div class="button_proj">
            <a>
              <button class="button">WEB</button>
            </a>
            <a >
              <button class="button" url>SOURCE</button>
            </a>
          </div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <!--Section Divider-->
    <div class="s-divider"></div>

    <!--Skills Section-->
    <div id="skills">
      <h2>SKILLS</h2>
      <div class="skills_img">
        <img src="images/CSS_logo.png" alt="CSS_logo" />
        <img src="images/HTML_logo.png" alt="HTML_logo" />
        <img src="images/JS_logo.png" alt="JS_logo" />
        <img src="images/Csharp_logo.png" alt="Csharp_logo" />
        <img src="images/Git_logo.png" alt="Git_logo" />
        <img src="images/Python_logo.png" alt="Python_logo" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="main.js" defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

tired everything I could find on stack overflow and other sites regarding this or similar problems

Comment: Your relevant "*[mcve]*" code is required to be in your question (as text/code, not an image or link elsewhere), could you please [edit] your question to include that code. You should probably also read the "*[ask]*" guidance also.

Comment: I just copied, pasted and runned your code, seems to be working like expected i guess: https://imgur.com/a/dUxvVZI

Comment: The example is working as expected for me as well. (You erroneously put the HTML and CSS into two separate snippets. I submitted an edit to combine them so that the example will actually be runnable.)

Comment: @PauloFernando I've tried it on Windows machine and android phone for mozilla and chrome, it works. But as for Safari, both desktop and mobile, the issue persists. I've added -webkit- for compatibility, but it didn't resolve this.

Comment: I tested on windows safari app, didn't even get the skew: https://prnt.sc/78cYGWkYAY2u to make it work in safari you will probably need javascript..